# Bought a brand new SSD Samsung 850 evo, plugged in, restart macbook, hold option, and no disk utility screen

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ssd, install

So I bought Samsung 850 EVO, 250GB, and plugged it into my Macbook (Mid-2010, Macbook 7.1). I installed it without mounting screws, because I don't have screwdriver to unscrew the ones from the old HDD (Toshiba, 256GB). I have on a USB thumb drive (16GB) installation of El Capitan, made using DiskMaker 5. Surprisingly, when I restarted the laptop and immediately hold the Option key, nothing happens except the blue screen and a cursor on it. There is no recovery screen or anything (that was actually supposed to happen). I then replaced the SSD with my old HDD and everything works fine as before. Anyone knows what might be the problem? I will go and buy the adequate screwdriver, but I don't know which one though. WHen I try manual installation through terminal I get this message at the end of the process:

Couldn't mount dmg /Volumes/Install OS X El Capitan/Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg (error code 112)Mount of outer dmg failed.

Comment: This has just fell onto my mind, because I had this option when I created thumb drive, but I didn't select it, because I followed the instruction (see below my comment for this site, mashable.com). It might not be bootable. And the reason why it starts with my old harddisk is because it has something to boot from (something bootable - my hard disk). I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: Better stay with the option 2 on the linked site  (Terminal method to create a bootable installer thumb drive).

Comment: Why do you think so? It seems very reliable.

Comment: Diskmaker5 is just an Apple Script wrapper for the terminal command (`sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Con...`) mentioned in option 2 step 2. Then you can just use the original ;-)

Comment: woah, I guess it is a big difference then! :)

Comment: woll, keep u guyz posted.

Comment: I set it to be bootable, and the same happens! Problems, problems.

Comment: How do you set it to bootable? Usually this is **not** necessary!

Comment: Using terminal, I don't set bootable. Using the DiskMaker, I just choose something that says bootable master record instead of GUID mapping option.

Comment: I tried to install other OSX using the CD rom that I have (an original CD with another older mac osx on it). And during the installation process I get message "OS X can't be installed on this computer". I think I will have to return my SSD to the shop and get my money back, since it doesn't work any how.

Comment: It **has** to be a GUID partition map. just keep with option 2 step 2

Comment: Yes, tried that too. Doesn't work, I can't see the SSD. I am starting to think that SSD is the cause of problem, since I can't install OS X from the original Mac OS X installation CD. It starts the isntallation and then quits (red above).

Comment: I don't think that SSD is the problem now, because I tried to install OS X from CD, with my old HDD inside and I get the same message "OS X can't be installed on this computer."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different thumb drive, because it sounds like yours is broken. Do the same thing and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yup, this solved the problem, I had another similar question, but this is the answer to that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mistaken. Holding down <kbd>Option</kbd> will bring up the "select startup disk" menu (EFI booter), and *not* Recovery.

To view Disk Utility, hold <kbd>Command+R</kbd>. This will boot you into Recovery where you can open Disk Utility. This is, however, provided that you have installed El Capitan onto the SSD.

Comment: I was following this, they say Option key: http://mashable.com/2015/10/01/clean-install-os-x-el-capitan/#JIhgKumZjEqm

Comment: Option is to select which drive to boot from. If you see nothing, that's really weird. Perhaps hold it longer and wait a bit?

Comment: I did that. I think I might have startes holding it too late in the procesa...

Comment: Press and hold Option, *then* press the power button

Comment: I tried again with USB formatted with Bootable Master record or something (instead of the default option for erase given through EL Capitan's Disk Utility)

Comment: You mean Master Boot Record (MBR) instead of GUID Partition Table (GPT)? MBR is used primarily by Windows systems.

Comment: yes i tried that instead.