# Can I use SSD Samsung 850 EVo , 250gb in Macbook Mid-2010 (Macbook 7.1) without mounting screws?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, hardware

Can I use SSD Samsung 850 EVO , 250gb in Macbook Mid-2010 (Macbook 7.1) without mounting screws? I got a brand new SSD but without mounting screws. There are mounting screws on my HDD currently, but I can't pull them out of it, because I don't have a screwdriver.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your Mac with the SSD unmounted, but it is HIGHLY DISCOURAGED. This is because:

- The connection can come lose, which will cause kernel panics and data loss
- Could also harm the SSD if it bounces around in the case
- Movement could cause damage to internal components, such as connections.

The best thing to do is to mount the drive. Post a picture of the mounting screws, and someone here will point you to the right screwdriver. They're almost always cheap, and it's worth the money.

Comment: thanks. I bought a screwdriver and I can unscrew them now.

Comment: I installed the SSD inside, using the mounting screws from the old hard drive. I can't install OSX on it. I tried using the bootable thumbdrive but I can't install it (see my other question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229435/bought-a-brand-new-ssd-samsung-850-evo-plugged-in-restart-macbook-hold-option).

Comment: I installed the SSD inside, using the mounting screws from the old hard drive. I can't install OSX on it. I tried using the bootable thumbdrive but I can't install it (see my other question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229435/bought-a-brand-new-ssd-samsung-850-evo-plugged-in-restart-macbook-hold-option). I also tried installing an older versoin of OSX on it using the CD, and it says "OSX Can;t be installed on this computer" during the installation process, and I must restart computer or recover from time machine, which I don't have.

Comment: So the older version I tried which throws "OSX Can't be installed on this computer" is 10.6.3, but it is not relevant, but nevertheless doesn't work either.